# optimizing mod_fcgid for a dedicated site

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-fcgid

I'm using mod_fcgid and I'm trying to find resources on how I can optimize it for running a dedicated website, but have had no luck... So far I have:

I've got apache2 running and I'm trying to have php processes spawned and always running so apache does not have to keep spawning them.

```
# Fastcgi configuration for PHP5
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
MaxRequestsPerProcess 5000
# Maximum number of PHP processes.
MaxProcessCount       8
# Number of seconds of idle time before a process is terminated
IPCCommTimeout        1800
IdleTimeout           1800
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php5
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php4
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php3
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php2
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .phtml
```

Answer (score 2):

- 'IPCCommTimeout' may be too large. Set the normal limit(60-180)
- 'IdleTimeout' set to 3600 or higher
- 'DefaultMaxClassProcessCount' set to (number or CPU core)
- 'ProcessLifeTime' set to 7200
- 'MaxProcessCount' set large 'DefaultMaxClassProcessCount'(2*'DefaultMaxClassProcessCount')